# Merge partial pickle files to get back my original pickled model

Tags: python, github, merge, pickle, streamlit

I have pickled a RF model on my machine and its size is of 360Mb,
Now I want to upload it to GitHub but I cannot do it by file upload nor by the terminal,
I tried git lfs too but it didn't work neither !!

Finally, I have split the pickle file into 15 parts, uploaded all of them to Github in a separate folder,
But now, I would like to know how can I merge them to get the complete model on streamlit ?!
What should I do to have the complete model in streamlit ? and is there a way to merge the files on GitHub ?

Thanks

Comment: 360Mb is a lot for a RF model. you can try compressing the model when you pickle it. That need some more time, but the filesize decreases.
how did you split your pickle files. You need to concat them the same way as you splitted them.

Comment: @Exciter thank you very much. The problem is solved by compressing the model. I used lzma and it passed from 360Mb to 32Mb and then used the terminal to push. Thanks again

Comment: @Exciter: probably worth turning the comment into an answer for amk to accept.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to [@Exciter's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71763525/merge-partial-pickle-files-to-get-back-my-original-pickled-model/71889754#comment126821641_71763525), the problem is solved by compressing the model.

> 360Mb is a lot for a RF model. you can try compressing the model when you pickle it. That need some more time, but the filesize decreases. how did you split your pickle files. You need to concat them the same way as you splitted them.

I used lzma and it went from 360Mb to 32Mb. I then used the terminal to push.